# Get geometry from a varchar(max) in an update query

Tags: sql-server, geometry

I've got a table full of WKT (well known text) in a varchar(max) column. This is formatted exactly as geometry. So, for example, one of the values is:

```
POLYGON ((174.893529167059 -37.0260462162965,174.89351593407 -37.0260221329151,174.893508034056 -37.0260077002766,174.893444415879 -37.0258916500588,174.893416916056 -37.0258414997842,174.893481733297 -37.0258186834198,174.893492016755 -37.0258150663863,174.89349653254 -37.025823316032,174.893512415978 -37.0258522827285,174.893556883897 -37.0259333832477,174.893591032956 -37.0259956661343,174.893604265986 -37.0260197504078,174.893575149738 -37.0260300006258,174.893529167059 -37.0260462162965))
```

However, I need to convert this varchar(max) field into a geometry field. Unfortunately, SQL Server needs to have some other information in order to do this, so I can't just change the type of the field from varchar(max) to geometry.

I've created a blank geometry column in the same table (MyGeometry) but I'm failing in trying to convert it. Here is my code (where 2193 is the CRS I'm dealing with). WKT is my varchar(max) field and MyGeometry is my new geometry field.

```
UPDATE       MY_TABLE
SET                MyGeometry = geometry::STPolyFromText('' + WKT + '', 2193)
```

EDIT - currently coming back saying the WKT is not valid (System.FormatException 24111 - the input isn't valid).

Which is strange as it matches up perfectly with some other inputs I have in how it's styled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do :
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET MyGeometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((174.893529167059 -37.0260462162965,174.89351593407 -37.0260221329151,174.893508034056 -37.0260077002766,174.893444415879 -37.0258916500588,174.893416916056 -37.0258414997842,174.893481733297 -37.0258186834198,174.893492016755 -37.0258150663863,174.89349653254 -37.025823316032,174.893512415978 -37.0258522827285,174.893556883897 -37.0259333832477,174.893591032956 -37.0259956661343,174.893604265986 -37.0260197504078,174.893575149738 -37.0260300006258,174.893529167059 -37.0260462162965))', 0)

You can change that 'POLYGON....' to your VARCHAR(MAX) field.

0 at the end, which is SRID only relevant if you're using Geography.

Comment: UPDATE       MY_TABLE
SET                MyGeometry = geometry::STPolyFromText(WKT, 2193)

Comment: You don't need double single quote on WKT. WKT is already a text. (assuming WKT is your column name)

Comment: Have tried `UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MyGeometry = GEOMETRY::STPolyFromText(WKT,2193)` (and also STGeomFromText) with still no luck. Maybe I do have some invalid geometry in there, but I doubt it.

Comment: `code`UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MyGeometry = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(WKT,2193).MakeValid();

Comment: This is working on a fair few of them, but not quite all. I think some of them must genuinely have some invalid WKT in them.

Comment: In that case, update that field one by one using a cursor. At the end of the process, you can select all rows that have invalid geometry. That's what I usually do.

Comment: Will probably try that later - at the moment I'm just concentrating on getting values onto a map. The amount of records is quite big - nearly one million.

Comment: 1 million is not that many. I rather do it slower in cursor, knowing that you can update what you can and leave out the dodgy ones. Rather than do it in one update statement, knowing it will rollback. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try :-

```
UPDATE  MY_TABLE SET MyGeometry = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((174.893529167059 -37.0260462162965,174.89351593407 -37.0260221329151,174.893508034056 -37.0260077002766,174.893444415879 -37.0258916500588,174.893416916056 -37.0258414997842,174.893481733297 -37.0258186834198,174.893492016755 -37.0258150663863,174.89349653254 -37.025823316032,174.893512415978 -37.0258522827285,174.893556883897 -37.0259333832477,174.893591032956 -37.0259956661343,174.893604265986 -37.0260197504078,174.893575149738 -37.0260300006258,174.893529167059 -37.0260462162965))',4326);
```

The value of SRID passed should be 4326 and not 0

You can check the URL below. I found this information in another similar question (older post) so pasting it without any changes

I found solution, SQL Server Spatial Tools

http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/

Followings are the methods solved my problem.

IsValidGeographyFromText(string inputWKT, int srid)

Check if an input WKT can represent a valid geography. This function requires that the WTK coordinate values are longitude/latitude values, in that order and that a valid geography SRID value is supplied. This function will not throw an exception even in edge conditions (i.e. longitude/latitude coordinates are reversed to latitude/longitude).

SqlGeography MakeValidGeographyFromText(string inputWKT, int srid)

Convert an input WKT to a valid geography instance. This function requires that the WKT coordinate values are longitude/latitude values, in that order and that a valid geography SRID value is supplied.